# Landsat images with more than 3 colored bands

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat

I’m looking for a website where I can find Landsat images (or similar to it) with more than just 3 color bands. http://glovis.usgs.gov/ only gives me 3 bands. Is there a way to obtain more band?

Comment: I suspect the problem might be in what your software is showing, not in the data. When I get Landsat from GloVis, it's had all the bands.

Comment: I once ordered data from the glovis and I had to install bulk dowwnload application and wait for a few hours for the data to be prepared. -Just a comment.

Answer (score 3):

[Glovis](http://glovis.usgs.gov/) redirects you to [Earth Explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) for the actual download, so I often opt to use Earth Explorer directly.  There is another very good download site you may be interested in called [Reverb | Echo](http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/).  I have had issues in the past using Glovis with Google Chrome as the requisite pop-ups are blocked prior to download.  These are the correct steps to take in order to download the Level 1 data which is composed of all of the available reflectance bands:

**1) Go to [Glovis](http://glovis.usgs.gov/)--enable all pop-ups.**

**2) Select the centroid of your area of interest**

[image]

**3) Choose your sensor and acquisition date**

[image]

**4) Add the image to the queue**

[image]

**5) Send to cart**

[image]

**6) The browser will add a new tab, redirect you to Earth Explorer, and prompt you to "Sign in using your USGS registered username and password"**

[image]

**7) A new screen will appear with the available products for download**

[image]

**8) Again a new screen will appear and you can choose the specific products for download.  *Make sure to specify the Level 1 GeoTIFF Data Product***

[image]

If at any point a screen fails to appear in this tutorial, try a different browser and, if necessary, temporarily reduce your security settings

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) web site, I have used this site to download the full 7 bands.